# SQL Server Recursive Hierarchy Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

This is for SQL Server 2012. I need to generate a dataset containing links, and all links of links from a given starting ParentId given the following table

```
CREATE TABLE Relations (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentId INT NOT NULL,
    ChildId INT 
);
```

So for the following dataset:

```
1 A B
2 B C
3 C D
4 F D
5 F G
6 X Y
7 Y Z
```

Starting with C, I'd expected to get back rows 1 to 5 as they're all linked to C through either parent or child hierarchies. E.g. G has parent F, which is parent of D, which is child of C.

It's not a standard hierarchy  query as there's no real root, and I need to get links in both directions. So this means I can't use the CTE recursion trick.. here was my attempt:

```
--Hierarchical Query using Common Table Expressions 
WITH ReportingTree (Id, Parent, Child, Lvl) 
AS 
( 
    --Anchor Member 
    SELECT Id,
     ParentId,
     ChildId,
   0 as Lvl
FROM Relations WHERE ParentId = 9488 
UNION ALL 
--Recusive Member 
SELECT 
 cl.Id,
 cl.ParentId,
 cl.ChildId,
 r1.Lvl+1 
FROM [dbo].[CompanyLinks] cl 
    INNER JOIN ReportingTree r1 ON ReportingTree.Parent = cl.Child
    INNER JOIN ReportingTree r2 ON cl.FromCompanyId = r2.Parent  <-- errors
) 
SELECT * FROM ReportingTree
```

My second attempt involved a temp table and while loop. This works but turns out to be very slow:

```
BEGIN   
CREATE TABLE #R (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    ParentId INT NOT NULL,
    ChildId INT 
);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Parent ON #R (ParentId);
CREATE INDEX IX_Child ON #R (ChildId);

INSERT INTO #R
  SELECT Id,ParentId ChildId
    FROM Relations
    WHERE ParentId = 9488 OR ChildId = 9488;
WHILE @@RowCount > 0
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #R
    SELECT cl.Id,cl.ParentId, cl.ChildId
      FROM #R INNER JOIN
        Relations AS cl ON cl.ChildId = #R.ChildId OR cl.ParentId = #R.ParentId OR cl.ChildId = #R.Parent OR cl.ParentId = #R.Child
    EXCEPT
    SELECT Id,ParentId, ChildId
      FROM #R;  
END

SELECT * FROM Relations cl inner Join #Relations r ON cl.Id = #R.Id
DROP TABLE #R
```

END

Can anyone suggest a workable solution for this?

Comment: Each node has only one child?

Comment: No, there can be multiple children and multiple parents

Comment: I would use one CTE to recursively traverse down the hierarchy and another CTE to recursively traverse up the hierarchy, and UNION together both result sets.

Comment: @Biscuits This would leave some rows out, as a child, like `D`, can have multiple parents, like `C` and `F`.

Comment: My understanding is that you have many-to-many relationships between nodes (as opposed to one-to-many relationships as with classic trees). Surely, traversing down the hierarchy would return all nodes that descend from C and traversing up the hierarchy would return all ancestor-nodes of C. I don't see how any nodes, directly or indirectly related to C might possibly be left out using this method.

Comment: `D` is a child of `C`, so to reach `D` we have to go *down* the hierarchy. But then we have to go up so as to reach `F` and then down again so as to reach `G`.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean now. My suggestion is insufficient. Flood fill comes to mind. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We match every row with every other row based on every combination of parent and child ids, and save the path along the way. Recursively we do this matching and make the path, in order to avoid infinite loops we check the path is not traversed previously, finally we have all nodes that has a path to the desired node(`@Id`):

```
WITH cte AS ( 
        SELECT CompanyLinks.*, cast('(' + cast(ParentId as nvarchar(max)) + ',' 
                 + cast(ChildId as nvarchar(max))+')' as nvarchar(max)) Path 
          FROM CompanyLinks 
          WHERE ParentId = @Id OR ChildId = @Id
          UNION ALL 

          SELECT a.*,
               cast(
                     c.Path + '(' + 
                     cast(a.ParentId as nvarchar(max)) + ',' + 
                     cast(a.ChildId as nvarchar(max)) + ')' 
                   as nvarchar(max)
                   ) Path 
        FROM CompanyLinks a JOIN cte c ON 
              a.ParentId = c.ChildId 
              OR c.ParentId = a.ChildId 
              OR c.ParentId = a.ParentId 
              OR c.ChildId = a.ChildId 
            where c.Path not like cast(
                     '%(' + 
                     cast(a.ParentId as nvarchar(max)) + ',' + 
                     cast(a.ChildId as nvarchar(max)) + 
                     ')%' 
                   as nvarchar(max)
                   )

)
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, Company.Name, path from (
   SELECT distinct ParentId as id, path FROM cte
   union all 
   SELECT distinct ChildId as id, path FROM cte
) a inner join Company on Company.Id = a.Id
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1275da/11) for it.
If you want distinct nodes just use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id from (
   SELECT distinct ParentId as id FROM cte
   union all 
   SELECT distinct ChildId as id FROM cte
) a
```

at the end of query.

This query is actually a Breadth First Search on an un-directed graph.

**Note:** Based on Hogan comment, there is no need for checking the path, as there is a primary key in the relation table(which I did not noticed) we can look for the primary key in prior recursions to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: wouldn't a distinct id for a given node work the same as a "path"  seems simpler.

Comment: Yes, I added the path, just to visualize the search process.

Comment: Ah ok, you said "make the path in order to avoid" so I assumed that is what you meant.

Comment: No, no the path is necessary to avoid trapping in the loop, I meant including path in the result is for visualizing the search process . How we can give a distinct id to each node? can you elaborate more?

Comment: `Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,` <-- primary key is unique.  You can look for the primary key in prior recursions and not worry about matching paths.  It will also be much faster because it has an index.

Comment: Yes you are right, I did not noticed that the relation has a Primary Key,  usually the many-to-many relations does not have unique id, I worked based on this assumption.